# Is it possible schedule a deployment from Visual Studio 2019 (SSIS) to Sql Server Management Studio 2018?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, ssms, schedule

I have Visual Studio 2019 where I work on various SSIS packages and projects that I then deploy to SSMS 2018. I'm aware of how to deploy packages and projects in general using the deployment wizard, but I cannot seem to find if it is possible to schedule a deployment. We have a strict maintenance window for deployments and I don't always have the ability to be present  for these windows. The projects/packages are worked on locally, on a windows machine and are deployed to an on-prem server.

Comment: SSMS 2018 doesn't exist; do you mean SSMS 18 (which was released in 2019)? Also you don't deploy packages to SSMS; SSMS is just an IDE-like application. You deploy SSIS packages to SQL Server.

Comment: @ThomA  Yes, SSMS 18, and is it possible to schedule that deployment from Visual Studio 2019?